# Which comic books should I read to prepare for the Suicide Squad movie?

Tags: dc, comics, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad, suicide-squad-2016

In 2016 there is going to be some super intense comic book movies that I really want to see, *Suicide Squad*

I am very interested in the origin stories of the *Suicide Squad* villains, but I have no clue where to start reading the comics.

I am particularly interested in The Joker and Harley Quinn's background, it looked interesting. Also Enchantress and Deadshot.

I would like to read them in the most chronological way possible, but I know comic books are kind of funny about stuff like that.
Does anyone know where to start with this stuff?

Comment: I'm not deeply familiar of when it started, but it is a spin off created to justify why all the villains got free easily from arkham asylum and such, so Suicide Squad was created with the story that the goverment uses them for impossible suicide missions and in the counterpart they get freedom if they survive. On another note, did u google Suicide Squad first edition ?

Comment: Really, the only thing you need to have seen is *Man of Steel*, as this is a separate continuity from the comics, the Nolanverse, the Richard Donner movies, the DCAU, and the current and upcoming DC TV shows. All of the backstories from the comics may act as inspiration for the new version, but nothing is guaranteed to match.

Comment: Do either of you know of any comics that have the backstory for the suicide squad characters?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. I'm a Marvel kid. I'm sure one of our resident DC experts will be along soon.

Comment: You shouldn't accept answers so quickly. Give it a day or two for answers to roll in, especially given that this is a holiday weekend in the US, and you'll see a lot of high-quality answers to choose from. Accepting one early just discourages others from answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what continuity they're using for the film, but Harley Quinn's original continuity was Batman: The Animated Series. It's a great show if you're a fan of Batman, and it works as an introduction to Harley and her obsession with the Joker, so I'd recommend giving it a watch if you can.

Enchantress appears to be an ancient villain they revived and dusted off fairly recently; if you're into classic stuff, it looks like she debuted in Strange Adventures #187 back in 1966. The more recent run begins with Green Lantern vol 3 #118 and the Day of Judgement miniseries back in 1999, which then led into Green Lantern: Rebirth and Day of Vengeance, so those series might be the ones you want to pick up to get more about her.

Deadshot is a Batman villain as well, also dating back to the 50s. DC put out a collection called Deadshot: Beginnings, so I suggest that one for his backstory :)

The other thing you might want to look into is the actual comics of Suicide Squad, as I'm almost certain they'd recap the high points of each character's backstory there.